# Using A WrapPanel in a TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml, panel

I want to display data with level of detail, so i use a TreeView, but each detail is quite short, so i would like to use a WrapPanel (horizontal) to have many details per line.

Something like :

- This is an unexpanded item
- This is The Header of an expanded item

  Info 1   Info 2   Info 3   Info 4

  Info 5   Info 6   Info 7

So i tried defining TreeViewItem's Template but i could not get the wrappanel to
wrap. I have only one info per line, when info's datatemplate width is 100 and TreeView
is 500. i tried setting Width of WrapPanel, ItemsWidth, are other things with no success.

Any idea ?

EDIT : i finally got this to work with a 'simpler' solution. Still it seems that we
have to define the WrapPanel's Width, which make the solution less generic.

Here's the solution i came to : just defining, in a style, the ItemsPanel used in a
TreeViewItem :

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
   <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
       <Setter.Value>
              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel  Orientation="Horizontal"      
                            Width="520"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                            Margin="0" 
                            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                            IsItemsHost="True"  
                    />
              </ItemsPanelTemplate>
       </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

And i still let the not working solution here, for completeness sake.
(Why wouldn't it work ???)

```
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Grid Margin="2" Width="500">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <ContentPresenter Name="PART_Header"                 
                                      ContentSource="Header"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center" />

    !!!! this is the wrapanel not wrapping 
                    <ListBox     Name="AllItems"     Grid.Row="1"      >
                        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <WrapPanel  Orientation="Horizontal"   />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPresenter   />
                    </ListBox>

                </Grid> 

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="False">
                        <Setter
                                       TargetName="AllItems"
                                        Property="Visibility"                     
                                          Value="Collapsed" />
                  </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Do you see the WrapPanel at all? Does it have ScrollBars? Maybe try to disable them.

Comment: yes in fact as i said it works, except that it shows items as if the panel was a Vertical StackPanel. And it is horizontally centered, whatever i change. And yes it tried setting Horizontal ScrollViewer to Disabled, and it did not work.

Comment: And what happens if the WrapPanel is wider? Try setting a border to it and make sure it's indeed vertical or it's just the available space

Comment: as said above, solution found. Still donno why the other wouldn't work but..  Thx for support.

Comment: I'll write it as post, and if it does, mark it as answer so other users encountering the same issue can enjoy too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT : i finally got this to work with a 'simpler' solution. Still it seems that we
have to define the WrapPanel's Width, which make the solution less generic. 
(Maybe a binding of the width (but which ?) would solve this)

Here's the solution i came to : just defining, in a style, the ItemsPanel used in a
TreeViewItem :

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
   <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
       <Setter.Value>
              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel  Orientation="Horizontal"      
                            Width="520"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                            Margin="0" 
                            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                            IsItemsHost="True"  
                    />
              </ItemsPanelTemplate>
       </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must set

```
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
```

to your

```
<TreeView/>
```

not for

```
<WrapPanel/>
```

example:

```
<TreeView x:Name="fieldTreeView" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,0,5,0" Background="Beige"         
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource bla}}"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <TreeView.Resources>                
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Model:bla}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <TextBox Text=""/>
                </StackPanel>        
            </DataTemplate>                
        </TreeView.Resources>
        <TreeView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>                    
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>                    
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemsPanel>
    </TreeView>
```

This solution works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try

1. Disable the scroll bars
2. Widen the WrapPanel and see the visual impact, is it effected?
3. Make a color border/background to track the actual size of the WrapPanel

These will help you trace the problem