# Treeview is clipping my items

Tags: c#, silverlight, treeview

I've got following code. Why are my items always clipped after about 70px

```
<sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="OptionsTemplate">
    <CheckBox IsTabStop="False" Content="{Binding EnumValue}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
<sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="EnumOptionsTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource OptionsTemplate}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding EnumType}"/>
</sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<sdk:TreeView x:Name="FilterTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding GeoObjectFilter}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EnumOptionsTemplate}">
    <sdk:TreeView.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="sdk:TreeView">
            <StackPanel Background="Transparent">
                 <ItemsPresenter x:Name="TreeItems" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </sdk:TreeView.Template>
</sdk:TreeView>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ho yes i had same issue when redefining the TreeView Template. By the way, i'm not sure you need to, since StackPanel is the Default Template. I got my (wrappanel) template to work by setting a style for ItemsPanel rather than redifining it. And i had to define some width also. Seems the only way to make the Treeview to scale is to bind the width.
See the answer i made to my question here :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8802718/856501

Comment: I just noticed that even <sdk:TreeView x:Name="FilterTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding GeoObjectFilter}" /> clips the headers for any reason.

Comment: try settings the widths : 1) of your templates elements (CheckBox / TextBlock ) / 2) the width of the TreeView / 3) the ItemWidth of the treeview.

Comment: Post the Xaml of your OptionsTemplate. Maybe the issue is there. Maybe you also set default templates for CheckBox/TextBlock that are not good. Try doing just a very small project with just your treeview and minimal stuff to get it working for a test, and only when (yes it will !) work, insert into your project.